# Cancel execution of an ActionFilter within an action api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to cancel the execution of an `ActionFiler` from inside an action in case a certain condition is met? For instance:

```
public LoadAttribute: Attribute, IActionFilter{ 

      public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
      {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals("post", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !context.Canceled)
            {
                Do Something;
            }
        }

      public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals("get", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Do Something; 
            }
        }
}
```

since the `ActionExecutedContext` has property named "Canceled", can I cancel the execution of the `ActionFilter` as described in the following code?

```
[Load]
[HttpPost]
public IActionFilter Add(SomeType someType){

    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        Cancel Load ActionFilter 
        Redirect to Index;
    } 
    return View(someType)
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're in `OnActionExecuted`, then yes, you can conditionally do things based on what happened in the action. Obviously, it wouldn't work with `OnActionExecuting`, as the action hasn't actually executed yet. What is the actual question here? Is there some issue you're encountering? As it stands, the answer to your question is fairly obvious, and doesn't really require a question in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: How can it be cancelled then, that is the question.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I think you didn't read the question carefully, please take a look at the if statement in the `ActionExecuted` method, and the psudocode

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking. Do you want to cancel it when the Model is invalid? At this point it's already too late as the action has already been executed and second, you can't return IActionFilter from a controller. Do you confuse that with IActionResult?

Comment: @Tseng: "Do you want to cancel it when the Model is invalid", are you serious? it's crystal clear in the psudocode I added!!

Comment: btw. why don't do the model validation inside the action filter in the first place?

Comment: @Tseng: sorry to say, but you have no idea what you are taking about.

Comment: Like I said, the only way to cancel it is to do that within the action filter (`OnActionExecuting`). Once the action is called, you can't cancel it anymore and on `OnActionExecuted` will be called in any way. To cancel a filter (and hence prevent action to be called) you have to set it's the result within the result (`context.Result = new EmptyResult()` or whatever you want to return).

Comment: @Tseng: Please read the code first. Still you have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: If you don't believe me, read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#cancellation-and-short-circuiting), which should be your first source rather than SO anways ;) And FYI, you can do model validation within action filter executing via `context.ModelState.IsValid`, because it's run after model binding (see graphic in the docs)

Comment: @Arrrr: I don't think you read my comment clearly. *How* you indicate that it's been cancelled is entirely up to you. There's many different ways you could indicate that. In `OnActionExecuted` you then look for that marker and if it's found, don't do what the filter does. I'm still not sure what the breakdown is here. Why don't you just *try* something. Then, if that doesn't work, you'll at least have some real code we can work with. Also, when people are trying to help you, it's best not to be rude. We're not paid for our time here, and it's just as easy to just let you fend for yourself.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: How can I cancel it from outside the filter in the middle of an Action API, do you understand now???

Comment: @Tseng: What you are saying is fully unrelated to what I asked. I didn't ask about validating the model in an actionfilter etc.

Comment: As far as I know you can't cancel it,there's access to the ActionExecuting/edContext there.That's why I said once inside the action "it's too late" already. Of course it's related because your "pseudo code" uses `ModelState.IsValid` as condition and this can clearly be done inside an action filter.Also a redirect is possible from action filter. The question you ignored is:Why you can't/don't want to use it there?Maybe invest some more time to make it clear what you tried, why you can't use it.Sounds just like you don't understand how action filters work and want copy 6 paste ready code instead

Comment: And the `Canceled` property is well documented in the above link. it says __Canceled - will be true if the action execution was short-circuited by another filter.__, it's not an arbitrary parameter you can set from any point of code to cancel it. It's set by the ASP.NET request pipeline when you short-circuit an filter (or you can set it yourself in `OnActionExecuted` since it has public setter.To be noted, you also can't cancel middleware. But since you provide lack of more information and refuse to accept that you can do the shown code inside filter, its hard to offer your help or a solution

Comment: @Tseng: It is 100% possible and the worst way I can do it is by messing with Http Pipelines. I'm looking for a built-in functionality though.

Comment: Unless you want to abuse headers or use `HttpContext.Items` (middleware use that to transport values down to actions and back, so other middlewares can use it), there is nothing you can do about it. And when you mess with either of one, it will still only be applicable to filters you write and check these parameters and not for built-in or 3rd party filters, where as using the documented method will also work with all filters. You won't get a really satisfying answer unless you accept the fact that each framework/stack is opinionated to a certain degree and dictates you how you should use it

Comment: @Tseng: If you think you are a software developer, you should then never believe that something `cannot be done`. And Http Headers are useful for scenarios like this. Anyways, I still think there is a more efficient option.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `HttpContext.Items` and use that to communicate between your filters and action. In your case, set `HttpItems["cancel"] = true` and then check that in `OnActionExecuted`.